# Error headers: ap_headers_output_filter() after putting cache header in htaccess file

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

Receiving error: [debug] mod_headers.c(663): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()

after I included this within the htaccess file:

```
# 6 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=518400, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 HOURS
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Any help is appreciated as to what I could do to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't seem like error. Maybe you just have log level set to debug. If you get error you would see [error] and not [debug] in the log entry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your configuration looks perfectly fine. You should just change LogLevel from debug to warn (or whatever your favorite level is).